Валидация не проходит с OnValidSubmit
Register model
RegisterViewModel registerData

 public class RegisterViewModel
 {
     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Email")]
     public string Email { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [DataType(DataType.Password)]
     [Display(Name = "Password")]
     public string Password { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Пароли не совпадают")]
     [DataType(DataType.Password)]
     [Display(Name = "Repeat password")]
     public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Surname { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Middlename { get; set; }
     public Gender_type Gender { get; set; }
     public string? Education { get; set; }
     public string? Work { get; set; }
     public string? Salary { get; set; }
     public string? Hobby { get; set; }
     public string? Goal { get; set; }

     [Range(18, 100)]
     public int age;
     public int height;
     public int weight;
     public IBrowserFile photo;
 }

Blazor razor page
 <Card Shadow="Shadow.Default">
     <CardBody>
         <EditForm Model="@registerData" OnValidSubmit="@Register">
             <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
             <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationSummary></Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationSummary>
             <Field>
                 <FieldLabel>
                     Your Email
                 </FieldLabel>
                 <FieldBody>
                     <TextEdit @bind-Value="@registerData.Email"  Placeholder="name@blazorise.com" Role="TextRole.Email" />
                 </FieldBody>
             </Field>

             <Field>
                 <FieldLabel>
                     Gender
                 </FieldLabel>
                 <FieldBody>
                     <RadioGroup @bind-Value="@registerData.Gender" TValue="Gender_type" Name="gender">
                         @foreach (var val in Gender_type.GetValues(typeof(Gender_type)).Cast<Gender_type>())
                         {
                             <Radio TValue="Gender_type" Value="@val">@(val.ToString())</Radio>
                         }
                     </RadioGroup>
                 </FieldBody>
                 
             </Field>

             <Field>
                 <FieldLabel>
                     Name
                 </FieldLabel>
                 <FieldBody>
                     <TextEdit @bind-Value="@registerData.Name" Role="TextRole.Text" autocomplete="Name" />
                 </FieldBody>
             </Field>

             <Field>
                 <FieldLabel>
                     Surname
                 </FieldLabel>
                 <FieldBody>
                     <TextEdit @bind-Value="@registerData.Surname" Role="TextRole.Text" autocomplete="Surname" />
                 </FieldBody>
             </Field>

Я ввожу все данные, но валидация не проходит   

По какой то причине @bind-Value= не привязывается
